# Crontab not running a shell script with echo command in it, despite working fine standalone

Tags: shell, echo, cron

Sorry to be so long, below is the related ‘env’ variable on my machine

```
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
HISTSIZE=1000
SUDO_USER=subhasish
SUDO_UID=500
USERNAME=root
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/subhasish
PWD=/backup
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
SUDO_GID=500
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/bin/env
```

### My shell script simply logging in to a router and fetching information,

```
#!/bin/sh 
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0

host=**********
port=23
login=*********
passwd=*******
passwd2=*******
cmd="term len 0"
cmd2="sh clock"
cmd3="sh ip accounting"

(echo open ${host} ${port}
sleep 1
echo ${login}
sleep 1
echo ${passwd}
sleep 1
echo en
sleep 1
echo ${passwd2}
sleep 1
echo ${cmd} 
sleep 1
echo ${cmd2}
sleep 1 
echo ${cmd3}
sleep 5
echo exit) | telnet >> file.txt

sed '/telnet/,/term len 0/d' file.txt >> file2.txt
mv file2.txt file.txt
```

---

This works fine standalone however with crontab, it is refusing to work.

```
crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh /backup/telnet.sh
```

if you do,  tail -f /var/log/cron, it show cron running but no file.txt is produced. I get file.txt when manually running it.

```
Feb 11 23:26:01 localhost CROND[29053]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /backup/telnet.sh)
Feb 11 23:28:01 localhost CROND[29074]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /backup/telnet.sh)
```

To test whether crontab actually working,I ran below 2 lines from crontab which worked fine.

```
#* * * * * touch /backup/testing.txt
#* * * * *  /backup/test.sh

where test.sh is,
cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
touch /backup/testing.txt
```

I figured echo from crontab is not possible may be,
i.e.  `* * * * * /bin/echo "Hello, world!"` doesn't work,
but, `* * * * * /bin/echo "Hello, world!" >> /backup/test.out` will give output test.out.
but here echo is inside the script, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What OS?  What does `/bin/sh --version` tell you?

Comment: you can find crontab issues in numerous posts here in SO. Have a look at those... Remember that your environment in the shell and when runned from crontab are completely different!

Comment: You write to `file.txt` in the current directory. I'm not sure if `cron` does promise anything about it (and what's the promise). Try using full pathname or `cd`ing to the right place.

Comment: [root@localhost backup]# /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[root@localhost backup]# cat /etc/redhat-release 

CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko file gets created fine running standalone, will there be a problem in cron because of it?

Comment: Maybe it gets created in cron too, but you don't know **where** it is created. Or maybe it *would* be created in cron, but you lack write permissions to the place **where** it would be created. Don't guess, just specify a full directory path, so you know that `>>file.txt` means some known location.

Answer (score 2):

Take in account that lines like these:

```
sed '/telnet/,/term len 0/d' file.txt >> file2.txt
mv file2.txt file.txt
```

Are not very good for a cronjob: you need to put absolute paths, because otherwise everything will be saved in /.

What I suggest is to change it for this:

```
sed '/telnet/,/term len 0/d' /dir/to/your/file/file.txt >> /dir/to/your/file/file2.txt
mv /dir/to/your/file/file2.txt /dir/to/your/file/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank You very much everybody. It was the problem really. It's fixed now :-).